# Page refresh everytime when selecting radio buttons with HTML editor control

Tags: html, asp.net

I have page with radio button list and HTML editor. With HTML editor control the page is refreshing every time I select radio button option even though I am using udpatepanel. How do I prevent the page refreshing?

Code is working fine. The issue is with HTML editor. every time I change the radio button option it is taking time (page blinking) to load the HTML editor control. 
        
    
    
    test page

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="SM22" runat="server" /> 
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel22" runat="server"> 
 <ContentTemplate>
<table style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
         <td style="width:30%;">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblJobType" runat="server" 
                  AutoPostBack="true"  onselectedindexchanged="rblJobType_SelectedIndexChanged"> 
                 <asp:ListItem Value="O" Text="One Time"></asp:ListItem>                
                 <asp:ListItem Value="D" Text="Daily" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="W" Text="Weekly"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="M" Text="Monthly"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Y" Text="Yearly"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
         </td>
         </tr>

         <tr id="test1" runat="server" visible="false">
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtOneTimeDt" runat="server" Text="Once"></asp:TextBox></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="test2" runat="server" visible="false">
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Daily"></asp:TextBox></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="test3" runat="server" visible="false">
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="Weekly"></asp:TextBox></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="test4" runat="server" visible="false">
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text="Monthly"></asp:TextBox></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="test5" runat="server" visible="false">
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text="Yearly"></asp:TextBox></td>
         </tr>
</table>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<br />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
 <ContentTemplate>
<ajaxToolkit:Editor  ID="heeEmail" Width="650px" Height="400px" runat="server"/>  
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Check if you are getting any JavaScript error?

Comment: what is the code inside rblJobType_SelectedIndexChanged? is that code updating any control outside updatePanel?

Comment: No. based on selection it displays the text box

Comment: if (this.rblJobType.SelectedItem.Value == "O")
        {
            test1.Visible = true;
            test2.Visible = false;
            .....

Comment: I did the same thing and it is working without postback on my machine. (IE shows errors on left bottom of status bar, Firefox and Chrome Ctrl+Shift+J). I think there is some javaScript error.

Answer (score 1):

Set the autopost property off for the control and then rather add a save / submit button.

Comment: Need to keep the AutoPostBack to true to display different panel basedn radio button selection.

Answer (score 1):

I found your code working properly when in rblJobType_SelectedIndexChanged I updated the text in textbox or show/hide the rows.

I suppose this is something related to updating any other control on your page which is outside udpate panel

Comment: Code is working fine. The issue is with HTML editor. every time I change the radio button option it is taking time (page blinking) to load the HTML editor control.

Comment: on my machine, it is not causing any blinking, and only the textboxs are displayed/hidden and value in that textbox is updated.

Comment: sorry, i've not checked with HTML editor as I do not have AjaxControlToolkit..... but as you have placed the HTML editor inside updatePanel, it is also refreshed with every postback. I think the editor is implemented as an IFrame, so flicker is supposed to happen

Comment: If you are using scriptmanager and updatepanel, It shouldn't flick. Is there any way to control that vibrate?

Comment: @user3217334 I saw this on the "controlling" of the blink.  I may help.  It certainly highlighted a few things I did not know:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx (See Update Highlighting)